# How can I build a local changelogs server for package changelogs

Tags: 16.04

So I have a local ubuntu repo server which serves out packages.

apt-cache search custompkg  - shows me the package.

After installing via : apt-get install custompkg, I cannot query the changelog for the package via : apt-get changelogs custompkg.

Error received is :

```
 E: Failed to fetch changelog:/custompkg.changelog  Changelog unavailable for custompkg
```

I can view the changelog via : less /usr/share/doc/custompkg/changelog.Debian.gz

but how can I make it work with the apt-get changelog command? I see that that reaches out to changelogs.ubuntu.com and that repo setup seems very similar to regular ubuntu repo.

What tools/how can I make apt-get lookup changelogs from a local changelog server?

I see there's an option in /etc/apt/conf.d -

```
cat 01-vendor-ubuntu
Acquire::Changelogs::AlwaysOnline "true";
```

But there's not much docs on what/how to make this point to a local changelog server nor how to set that up.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. I'm using aptly debian repo but couldn't make to see changelog after running `apt changelog package` and trying to find right answer in between imaginary answers of chatgpt. I hated to correct chatgpt and reading messages start with "I'm sorry....".

Answer (score 1):

## Detailed Explanation

From what I understand of APT internals, changelog servers need to be explicitly configured. I use reprepro for this, and will base my answer on that, as it wasn't mentioned explicitly in the question, but whatever tool you use should have similar concepts.

APT has settings under `Acquire::Changelogs::URI::`. The way APT knows how to get changelogs from packages from the official Debian and Ubuntu repositories is set as follows in the APT code:

```
apt-pkg/init.cc:208:   Cnf.CndSet("Acquire::Changelogs::URI::Origin::Debian", "https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/@CHANGEPATH@_changelog");
apt-pkg/init.cc:209:   Cnf.CndSet("Acquire::Changelogs::URI::Origin::Ubuntu", "https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/@CHANGEPATH@/changelog");
```

Note also the `Origin`. This will be a field in your `Release` file for your distribution on your apt server (default is blank). You can also set it to depend on for example the `Label` field. Reading the docs, it also seems you can set a `Changelogs` field in your `Release` file, though in practice that doesn't seem to be how the major distributions do it, nor can I find a way to do it with reprepro, so I'll assume you set `Origin` to `Custom` from here on out.

Note the `@CHANGEPATH@` substitution variable. This is substituted in the same way a package would be under `pool`. So, if you have a package `foo` of version `1.0.0-1` in the `main` component with the architecture `all`, APT will first look for the package under `/pool/main/f/foo/foo_1.0.0-1_all.deb`. The algorithm for the directory under the component name is that any package which starts with `lib` gets put in a directory with the first 4 letters of its name (`libfoo` would go under `libf/libfoo/`), while any other packages use only the very first letter (`foo` goes under `f/foo/`).

Similarly, if you for example create the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10-vendor-custom` (on the target computer, not the server), with the following contents:

```
Acquire::Changelogs::URI::Origin::Custom "https://customrepo.dev/changelogs/pool/@CHANGEPATH@/changelog";
```

If you then update APT and run `apt changelog foo`, APT will look for the changelog at `https://customrepo.dev/changelogs/pool/main/f/foo/foo_1.0.0-1/changelog`.

Now, whatever tool you use, you should be able to figure out how to configure your APT server to generate this whenever a package is uploaded, but if you use reprepro, there's a (somewhat poorly documented) tool already included. It's located under `/usr/share/doc/reprepro/examples/changelogs.example.gz`. Copy that file and unzip under your `conf/` directory, then add the following line to your `conf/distributions` file for the distribution you want to enable changelogs for:

```
Log:
 --type=dsc changelogs.example
```

and reprepro should automatically add the changelogs for you under `changelogs/pool/`. You can run `reprepro rerunnotifiers` to generate changelogs for all your packages that have already been uploaded.

## Step by Step

Assume the following:

- Using reprepro to manage packages on the server
- Under `conf/distributions`, the `Origin` field is set to `Custom`
- The repo is hosted at `https://customrepo.dev`
- You want to host the changelogs on the same server without doing anything fancy with it
- The target machine is already configured to pull the actual packages from the repo

First, add the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10-vendor-custom` with the following contents on the target machine:

```
Acquire::Changelogs::URI::Origin::Custom "https://customrepo.dev/changelogs/pool/@CHANGEPATH@/changelog";
```

Second, go to the base directory of your repository and run the following commands:

```sh
cp /usr/share/doc/reprepro/examples/changelogs.example.gz conf/
gunzip conf/changelogs.example.gz
chmod 755 conf/changelogs.example
printf "Log:\n --type=dsc changelogs.example\n" >> conf/distributions
```

Double check `conf/distributions` afterwards, there shouldn't be any empty lines between your `Log:` directive and the ones above for the distribution you're trying to configure, but that should be all you need.

Run `reprepro rerunnotifiers` to generate changelogs for all current source packages. Any new ones you add should have it included automatically. That should be all the configuration you need.